# Is there any way to get list of all rails resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to get all resources in project to log some actions on them. Is there any way to do this?

More specific, I'd like to get a hash of all resources and associated models, so i don't think rake output (and parsing it) isn't a suitable solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: If you think I'm crazy**

as I mentioned in the comments:

> if you take a look at the
>   [`mapper`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77627c5aa3b9aeb68a53ad4a700f5003f2f24089/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1772)
>   you would see that the keyword resource would expand to a number of
>   `get`s, `post`s, etc. So I would say that your best chance is go
>   through the paths and remember that the first part of the path is
>   either a namespace or a resource name. Howerver, it would get really
>   complicated for nested resources.

So I came up with a crazy idea: *parsing the `routes.rb` file*. You could read the `routes.rb` line by line and use a regex like `resource(s*) :(\w*)` to fine resources:

```ruby
regex = %r(resource(s*) :(\w*))
resources = []
routes = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "/config/routes.rb")).read
routes.each_line do |l|
  matches = regex.match l
  if matches && matches[1]
    resources << matches[1]
  end
end
```

This is however a very **inflexible** solution.

**If you want it in your browser**

Follow the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes):

> To get a complete list of the available routes in your application,
>   visit http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes in your browser while
>   your server is running in the development environment.

**If you want to show in the terminal**

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

if you want to filter it out:

```
bundle exec rake routes | grep 'my_namespace'
```

where `name_space` is any keyword you'd like!

**If you want to do it programmatically:**

```
Rails.application.routes.routes
```

For example this is the method I use to find routes with a given prefix:

```
def routes_starting_with(prefix)
    result = []

    Rails.application.routes.routes.each do |route|
      path = route.path.spec.to_s
      result << route if path.starts_with?("/#{prefix}")
    end

    result
  end
end
```

Comment: How it could help get the **list** of resources? With this code, I'm able to get routes starting with 'something', not resources alone.  Nevertheless, thank you.

Comment: @Clamoris if you take a look at the [`mapper`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77627c5aa3b9aeb68a53ad4a700f5003f2f24089/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb) you would see that the keyword `resource` would expand to a number of `get`s, `post`s, etc. So I would say that your best chance is go through the paths and remember that the first part of the path is either a namespace or a resource name. Howerver, it would get really complicated for nested resources.

Comment: @Clamoris now I added a crazy solution and reached my limits!

Answer (score 2):

[5.1 Listing Existing Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes)

> To get a complete list of the available routes in your application, visit http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes in your browser while your server is running in the **development** environment. You can also execute the `rake routes` command in your terminal to produce the same output.
>
> You may restrict the listing to the routes that map to a particular controller setting the `CONTROLLER` *environment* variable:

```
CONTROLLER=users bin/rake routes
```

Comment: http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes seems not working. Is it introduced in rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

I actually made a gem for that. It extendends Action Dispatch RouteSet an Mapper to populate an array of resources with a special option.

You can find it here: https://rubygems.org/gems/resources_nav